# Accessing nth value in a key-value pair in dictionary in Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a python dictionary of the type

```
     Mutual={'A':[[1],[2],[],[]],'B':[[1],[],[],[]]}
```

I want to access the elements for key 'A'.
  I tried this:

```
     count=0
     for z in range(2):
          print Mutual["A"][z][count]
          count+=1
```

I am getting the following error

```
     IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone suggest why is it so. Must be some silly mistake which I am unable to catch.

Comment: your value is a 1-element array (well if it was syntaxically correct). [mcve] please.

Comment: `{'A':[[1][2][][]],'B':[[1][][][]]}` is a syntax error, do you mean `{'A':[[1],[2],[],[]],'B':[[1],[],[],[]]}` or something else?

Comment: `for count in Mutual['A']: print count`

Comment: Oh yes I meant that only. Edited that. @Chris_Rands

Comment: I do not want lists as output. I want 1 and 2 as output and not [1][2][][] @AChampion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the first iteration, `Mutual["A"][z][count]` returns 1. On the next iteration `Mutual["A"][z][count]` is supposed to be the second element in the list `[2]` (z is 1 and count is 1 as well) which does not exist. That is why you get an `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

A suggested modification to your code could be:

```
 listA = Mutual["A"]
 for z in range(len(listA)):
      for w in range(len(listA[z])):
          print listA[z][w]
```

This way, if the inner lists are of size zero the inner loop will not be executed and therefore, you will not try to access an out of bounds index.

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate. Or tell me in the terms of code. What change needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

It is usual in python to iterate the actual elements vs. using `range()` and indexes:

```
for z in Mutual['A']:
    for count in z:
        print count
```